# Can I reduce the space between a sunburst chart and its color scale in Dash?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-express

This is my code:

```
fig = px.sunburst(df2, path=['Year', 'Quarter', 'Month'], values='V',
                        color='R',
                        color_continuous_scale='RdYlGn', color_continuous_midpoint=0
                        )
```

I want to reduce the space between the chart and its scale:

[image: Sunburst Chart]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anything [in the documentation](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/) about the padding between the sunburst chart and the colorbar except for setting a tight layout, but this doesn't reduce the padding by very much if at all. In general, the Plotly library gives you great interactive visualizations at the cost of tunability - especially `plotly.express` instead of `plotly.graph_objects`.

A good starting point might be to poke around in `fig.layout.template` as this shows you exactly what charts are used to create the sunburst chart and which of these parameters you might be able to modify (especially to change a parameter outside of the scope of the documentation)

A pretty hacky solution I thought of that might work, but might also change your aesthetic, would be increasing the thickness of the colorbar to decrease the space between the sunburst chart and colorbar itself. Here is an example:

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['continent', 'country'], values='pop',
                  color='lifeExp', hover_data=['iso_alpha'],
                  color_continuous_scale='RdBu',
                  color_continuous_midpoint=np.average(df['lifeExp'], weights=df['pop']))

## use a tight layout ##
fig.update_layout(margin = dict(t=0, l=0, r=0, b=0))

## increase the thickness of the colorbar in pixels
fig.layout.coloraxis.colorbar['thickness'] = 200
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [x-position of a plotly color bar](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/coloraxis/#layout-coloraxis-colorbar-x) with

```py
fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_x=0.7)
```